# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transfer-encoding')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, multer

i am puzzled with this problem. this taken my a lot time . yet not figure out any solution.

can you anyone can help me for this problem ?

I tried many things from stack overflow but didn't find any solution.

this is my file.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express').Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const File = require('../models/file');
const { v4: uuid4 } = require('uuid');


let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'uplods/'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uniqueName = `${Date.now()}-${Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, uniqueName)
    },
})

let upload = multer({
    storage,
    limit: { fileSize: 1000000 * 100 },
}).single('myfile');



express.post('/', (req, res) => {
    upload(res, req,  async (error) => {
        // validate request
        if (!req.file) {
            return res.json({ error: "Files are not validate :( " })
        }
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message })
        }

        // store in to databse 
        const file = new File({
            filename: req.file.filename,
            uuid: uuid4(),
            path: req.file.path,
            size: req.file.size
        })

        const response = await file.save();
         return res.json({ file: `${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/files/${response.uuid}` })
        // 
    })

})
module.exports = express;
```

this is my error :

[image: 1]

Comment: please any one can help ?

Comment: i am noob in programming can you give me proper code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your callback. Try to reorganize as below.

```
  let upload = multer({
    storage,
    limit: { fileSize: 1000000 * 100 },
  });

  express.post("/", upload.single("myfile"), async (req, res, error) => {
    // validate request
    // codes
  }
```